# Getting zero from Performance Counter

Tags: c#, wcf, wmi, performancecounter

See the code below please:

```
    PerformanceCounter total_cpu = new PerformanceCounter("Process", "% Processor Time", "_Total");
    return total_cpu.NextValue();
    //returns 0
```

**It returns 0**

Now, See this one:

```
    PerformanceCounter total_cpu = new PerformanceCounter("Process", "% Processor Time", "_Total");
    while (true)
    {
        float t = total_cpu.NextValue();
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);
        return t;
        //returns correct value (matched with Task Manager)
    }
```

I want to get the performance counter values (such as CPU usage) continuously through a WCF service every 2 seconds and Result will be shown on asp page using ajax.

Now the problem is that the correct method will create a loop for itself too. I tried to handle it by flags but didn't help.

Note: I also tried **WMI**, but it was not returned correct values.

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

For many counters, the first value is always 0. See the first Note in the Remarks section in the docs:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.performancecounter.nextvalue.aspx

What you should do is have a static instance of the counter that reads every two seconds in the background, storing that data where your service can get it. Upon every request, you can return the pre-fetched value instead of fetching from the counter every time.